# error c2675 using STL VS13 c++

Tags: c++, stl

I am keeping reading Stanford tutorials and currently solving tasks on STL. The task is to write a function which accepts a `map` with names of films and their rankings. This function should return a `set` container with top 3 films according to critics review. Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct compare {
    bool operator() (const double& a, const double& b) const {
        return (a > b);
    }
};

set <string> list(map <double, string, compare>& films) {
    set <string> critics;
    map<double, string, compare> ::iterator it = films.begin();
    if (films.size() <= 3) {
        critics.insert(films.begin()->second, films.end()->second);
    }
    else { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i, ++it){
            critics.insert(it->second);
        }
    };
    return critics;
}


int main() {
    map <double, string, compare> films;
    films[5.0] = "a";
    films[8.0] = "b";
    films[10.0] = "c";
    films[7.4] = "d";
    set <string> critics = list(films);
    copy(critics.begin(), critics.end(), ostream_iterator <string>(cout, " "));
    cin.get();
}
```

Unfortunately, it keeps on throwing out an error:

```
error C2675: unary '++' : 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

I have read MSDN documentation on the error but as I am new to this could not understand the meaning of the problem. Could you, please, hint me at that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
critics.insert(films.begin()->second, films.end()->second);
```

is invalid. The compiler consideres arguments `films.begin()->second` and `films.end()->second` of type `std::string` as a pair of iterators and tries to apply operator ++. Of course this results in an error.

You should use standard algorithm `std::transform` with `std::insert_iterator` that to copy strings from the map to the set.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::map<double, std::string, std::greater<double>> m =
    {
        { 2.2, "B" }, { 1.1, "A" }, { 4.4, "D" }, { 5.5, "E" }, { 3.3, "C" }
    };

    for ( const auto &p : m )
    {
        std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
    }

    std::set<std::string> s;

    std::transform( m.begin(), std::next( m.begin(), 3 ), 
                    std::inserter( s, s.end() ),
                    []( const auto &p ) { return p.second; } );

    for ( const auto &t : s ) std::cout << t << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5.5 E
4.4 D
3.3 C
2.2 B
1.1 A
C D E
```

Comment: @Lightning Racis in Obrit   Ciao. Come va?

Comment: Bine, mulțumesc. Și dumneavoastră?